# Escape Unicode Characters for iOS

Tags: ios, unicode, swift

There are some Unicode arrangements that I want to use in my app. I am having trouble properly escaping them for use.

For instance this Unicode sequence:

If I escape it using an online tool i get: \ud83c\udd70

But of course this is an invalid sequence per the compiler:

```
var str = NSString.stringWithUTF8String("\ud83c\udd70")
```

Also if I do this:

```
var str = NSString.stringWithUTF8String("\ud83c")
```

I get an error "Invalid Unicode Scalar"

I'm trying to use these Unicode "fonts":
http://www.panix.com/~eli/unicode/convert.cgi?text=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

If I view the source of this website I see sequences like this:

```
&#x1D552
```

Struggling to wrap my head around what is the "proper" way to work with/escape unicode.

And simply need a to figure out a way to get them working on iOS.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens when you do `var str = \uD83D\uDD70"`?

Comment: Is there a way to know what is valid and what is not valid and how to properly convert? I would like to learn how to properly convert any unicode characters - understand the "why" behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift is an early Beta, is is broken in many ways. This issue is a Swift bug.

```
let ringAboveA:       String = "\u0041\u030A" is Å and is accepted  
let negativeSquaredA: String = "\uD83D\uDD70" is  and produces an error
```

[image]

Both are decomposed UTF16 characters that are accepted by Objective-C. The difference is that the composed character  is in plane 1.

Note: to get the UTF32 code point either use the OSX Character Viewer or a code snippet:

```
NSLog(@"utf32: %@", [@"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding]);
```

utf32: <0001f170>

To get the Character Viewer in the Apple Menu go to the "System Preferences", "Keyboard", "Keyboard" tab and select the checkbox: "Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar". The "Character View" item will be in the menu bar just to the left of the Date.

[image]

After entering the character right (control) click on the character in favorites to copy the search results.

Copied information:

NEGATIVE SQUARED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
Unicode: U+1F170 (U+D83C U+DD70), UTF-8: F0 9F 85 B0

Better yet: Add unicode in the list on the left and select it.
[image]

Comment: HI 
I Need to Convert Non- English characters to Unicode like (ud100 or fh123..) , how to do in swift

Comment: In a literal use `\ud100` or in the viewer as in the answer enter `d 1 0 0` and get 턀. If the comment is a surrogate pair see the answer by @nathan. I don't understand: `fh123..` in the comment.

Comment: I have chinese text ,i need to form that text to Unicodes like \u2345 .... and send to server, How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

`\ud83c\udd70` is a UTF-16 surrogate pair which encodes the unicode character  (U+1F170). Swift string literals do not use UTF-16, so that escape sequence doesn't make sense. However, since 1F170 has five digits you can't use a `\uXXXX` escape sequence (which only accepts four hexadecimal digits). Instead, use a `\UXXXXXXXX` sequence (note the capital `U`), which accepts eight:

```
var str = "\U0001F170" // returns ""
```

You can also just paste the character itself into your string:

```
var str = "" // returns ""
```

Comment: Nathan - how did you figure out the 8 digit version - I would like to be able to convert these on my own

Comment: @Spentak I used Character Viewer. If you paste a character into the search field and click the result, it will display the Unicode code point in the bar on the right. ([screenshot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2ry6jpi.jpg))

Comment: @nathan Thanks for the tip on the Character Viewer!