# how to print € symbol with star micronics SDK?

Tags: ios

i have star micronics tsp650 and im implementing SDK in my app, but i cant print the € symbol

someone knows what is the code to print it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally STAR MICRONICS support answer me

the code to print € symbol is

```
[commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x1d\x74\x04"
               length:sizeof("\x1b\x1d\x74\x04")-1]; //meto Euro

[commands appendBytes:"\xD5"
               length:sizeof("\xD5")-1]; //meto euro
```

Comment: did you faced the problem with **£** symbol ?

Comment: @GaurangMakwana to print the £ sign use: [commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x1d\x74\x03\x9c" length:sizeof("\x1b\x1d\x74\x03\x9c")];

Comment: Link for anyone wanting the £ symbol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865680/facing-issue-with-printing-%C2%A3-symbol-with-star-micronics-sdk

Answer (score 0):

€ in hex byte values:
UTF16: 20AC
UTF8:  E2 82 AC

```
char utf8[]  = "\xE2\x82\xac";
char utf16[] = "\x20\xAC";
NSLog(@"utf8:  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:utf8 length:3 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"utf16: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:utf16 length:2 encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding]);

NSString *cost = @"156.95 \xE2\x82\xac\r\n"; // dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"Cost: %@", cost);

NSMutableData *commands = [NSMutableData new];
[commands appendData:[@"156.95 \xE2\x82\xac\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"commands: %@", commands);
```

NSLog output:

```
utf8:  €  
utf16: €  
cost: 156.95 €   
commands: <3135362e 393520e2 82ac0d0a>
```

Comment: but how to put? \x20ac? or \xe282ac?

Comment: Dont works, here is my code:


[commands appendData:[@"156.95 \xE2, \x82, \xac \x20, \xAC \r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

Comment: nope :( still doesnt works, with UTF8 dont print the symbol, with utf16 error conversion to input utf8

Maybe is some other ascii code?

Comment: I have added the code you are using as an example. The Euro symbol can not be represented in ASCII so NSASCIIStringEncoding can not be used,  NSUTF8StringEncoding must be used. Also only utf8 hex can be used in string literals, not utf16 or utf32.

Comment: If i put: [commands appendData:[@"156.95 \xE2\x82\xac \r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

It print another extrange symbol, maybe is printer encription problem

Comment: Yeah, it must be a printer issue. Here is a link to how to [enable the character viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24204168/451475), it will allow you to see the codes for all the unicode characters.