# Facing issue with printing £ symbol with star micronics SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing

I have star micronics mPOP 2-inch bluetooth printer and I have integrated star micronics iOS SDK into my application.

I can't print **'£' symbol** with star micronics sdk. Anyone knows what is the code to print £ symbol?

I found the similar question for other symbol but it doesn't meet my requirement.

> URL : [how to print € symbol with star micronics SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296684/how-to-print-%E2%82%AC-symbol-with-star-micronics-sdk)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first command in your linked answer selects cod page 858. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_858 The £ symbol is 0x9c so you should send 9c instead of d5

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried with the 9c but it doesn't print the **£** symbol.

**Here is the code.**

    [commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x1d\x74\x04"
                                       length:sizeof("\x1b\x1d\x74\x04")-1]; 
    [commands appendBytes:"\x9C"
                                       length:sizeof("\x9C")-1];

Comment: The sizeof doesn't look right to me. I think that was a mistake in the original answer just put 4 and 1 for length

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution with following code.

Code to print **'£'** symbol.

```
[commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x1d\x74\x04"
               length:sizeof("\x1b\x1d\x74\x04")-1]; 
[commands appendBytes:"\x9c"
               length:sizeof("\x9c") - 1];
```

Here is the reference link for other symbols.

> URL : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_858

Thanks @Paulw11 for the help.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for the help.

Comment: what character encoding to use for string data with this? i used NSUTF8StringEncoding but its not working...

Comment: @YunusSaha Please use NSASCIIStringEncoding for character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these documents to print any character using the character code tables to find the table and the character position: http://www.kioskproapp.com/api/StarPrinter/star-character-code-table.pdf

For example, the £ symbol would be on page 3, position 9C. You can then change the code page using the command `ESC GS t n`. where n is the page number.

```
"\x1b\x1d\x74\x03"
```

Find more info on this command at http://www.starmicronics.com/support/mannualfolder/starprnt_cm_en.pdf page 2-4.

Then you can simple print the £ sign by printing 9c

```
"\x9c"
```

Remember to change back to code page 0, or you might see some odd characters:

```
"\x1b\x1d\x74\x00"
```

If you can't find the character in any of the tables then you can save your own to memory. Check out this post for more info about that: [Star micronics mpop iOS SDK - Save and print a character using the blank code page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041943/star-micronics-mpop-ios-sdk-save-and-print-a-character-using-the-blank-code-pa/39170504#39170504)

Answer (score 0):

For someone landing on here from Android and have spent hours finding it.
Do this:

`builder.appendInternational(ICommandBuilder.InternationalType.UK);
builder.append((byte) 0x23); //imagine searching through those numbers one by one!`